# Modify bootstrap on joomla website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

My website is joomla based and i want to modify the responsive bootstrap layout, to fit all the website on any resolution mobile/tablet etc.

To give you an example i want it to be just like www.hays.com .
When i enter hays on my phone the website just fit himself on all the screen, and i don't need to slide right to see all the website witch is curently happening in my website.

My website is www.citadella.co.uk

I have already tried to copy paste all the @media style with the full width one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the following file:

```
templates/tz_lania/index.php
```

In here you will see some tags with the class `container`. You need to change all of these to:

```
class="container-fluid"
```

Once done, you will also see some tags with the class `row`, which you will need to change to:

```
class="row-fluid"
```

This will ensure your site always uses 100% of any screen width. Hope this helps

**Update:**

Right ok, I wasn't aware that this was a T3 Framework bssed template. Ensure you have the T3 Framework plugin enabled first of all. If you can't find it in the plugin manager then you [download](http://www.joomlart.com/forums/downloads.php?do=file&id=3273) and install it.

If you already have it installed and enable, then go to your template options and under the tab called **General**, make sure you have **Responsive** turned **ON**

Comment: thanks for the answer but i cant find any class="container/row into that file

Comment: Can you provide a download link for your template if its free?

Comment: responsive in my template is on and the t3 framework plugin it is there and enabled. :P ...dunno what to do next?!

Comment: still i didnt managed to fix it...if you can see this loader maybe you can help me :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess you aren't using the classes of bootstrap that provide reposiveness on your Joomla template. If you look at bootstrap examples (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started) you will see in their code the use of classes like "col-lg-6". On a quick look on your site I didn't see any use of these classes, but I can't be sure.

Comment: These classes were introduced in Bootstrap 3.x and Joomla 3 uses Bootstrap 2.x still ;)